# ffmepg video from uneven sequence of png images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, screencast

I'm going to make a video from series of screenshots (.png files). For each screenshot there is assosiated timestamp information about when it was taken. The time intervals between screenshots may vary and it's highly desired to preserve that difference in the video.

Is there a way to use single `ffmpeg` command/API providing to it sequence of image + time (or frame) offset and getting one video file as output? 
By now I have to generate short video files of custom length for each image, and then merge them manually:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i image1.png -c:v libx264 -t 1.52 video1.avi
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i image2.png -c:v libx264 -t 2.28 video2.avi
...
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i imageN.png -c:v libx264 -t 1.04 videoN.avi


ffmpeg -i "concat:video1.avi|video2.avi|...videoN.avi" -c copy output.avi
```

This is quite ok, while intervals are large, but the whole approach seems to me a bit fragile.

Comment: is it possible for you to numerically sequence the image based on the timestamp. Then we can use certain commands in ffmpeg to create the video file

Comment: @shri yes, I can manipulate the data in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).

[image]
<sub>Example using 2, 4, and 0.25 seconds.</sub>

1. Make a text file indicating the desired duration per file:

   ```
   file 'image1.png'
   duration 1.52
   file 'image2.png'
   duration 2.28
   file 'image3.png'
   duration 1.04
   ```

   You may have to repeat the last `file` and `duration` lines to get it to display the last frame.
2. Run the `ffmpeg` command:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
   ```

Comment: May you please explain the reason why last line should be repeated?
Suppose I have one png file at all. I have to repeat it or otherwise the whole movie is black except for the first frame. This is really strange bahavior.

Comment: @MaximKornienko Can you show your command and complete console output? A link to a pastebin will be good.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but the reason for why the last frame has to be repeated is explained in the [docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow): It's just a quirk of ffmpeg.

Answer (score -1):

If you can sequence the images based on the timestamp value, and if the images are of the same size, then you can the below command to get the video:

```
ffmpeg -framerate X -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Refer to the below url which gives you various command option to generate the video:

[FFmpeg Wiki: Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to all images having the same interval in the video?

Comment: yes  since the frame rate will be based on the x value. but there is also another option provided. "ffmpeg also supports bash-style globbing (* represents any number of any characters). This is useful if your images are sequential but not necessarily in a numerically sequential order as in the previous examples." in that case may be you can try to give your input with out changing the sequence and try it.

Comment: @shri it doesn't seem to work. I have a sequence of frames taken from a 30fps source, but many frames are missing due to the capture process. With globbing (`-pattern_type glob -i "frames/frame_*.png"`), the resulting video is much too fast. I've tried adding `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` and `-ts_from_file 1` but neither make any difference, even though the file modification times make sense (e.g. frame 30 is 1 second after frame 0). Maybe the glob reader discards modification times.